# Is it possible to disable throttleLast for period of time?

Tags: rx-java, rx-java2

My events comes from system at rapid time, but i need only last actual every 500 ms, so i use tthrottle . However after user made input, i'd like to disable throtle for 1 event  to make it proceed asap. Is there a way to disable it or indicate that next event should be forced?

```
observable = observable.throttleLast(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS);
observable = observable.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread());
observable = observable.subscribeOn(Schedulers.io());
observable.subscribe(...)
```

Comment: No, and what you describe is a pretty peculiar behavior. Why do you want the very next item after the throttled one to be processed immediately?

Comment: Not after throttle. I want turn of it.
eg chaing of event throttled---user make input, all events processed unthrotled for 1 second --- eventra are throtled again

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't turn the behavior of `throttleLast` off. The closest thing you could do is publish the sequence and switch between two processing modes:

```java
source
.observeOn(Schedulers.single())
.publish(o ->
    o.throttleLast(500, TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS, Schedulers.single())
    .take(1)
    .concatWith(o.takeUntil(1, TimeUnit.SECONDS, Schedulers.single()))
    .repeat()
    .takeUntil(o.ignoreElements().toObservable())
)
```

So throttle for 500 milliseconds, which should result in one item, then switch to the unthrottled sequence for 1 second, then repeat from the beginning with throttling, etc. To avoid any dataloss due to the mode switch, you should involve a single-threaded scheduler such as `single()`, but this is still not 100% dataloss free. The best is a dedicated unique operator.

**Edit:** There is a need for an additional `takeUntil` to stop the repeat if the source terminated on its own.